# readAsStringAsync file is not readable

Tags: react-native, expo

```
export async function addUserCredentials(username, password) {
 try {
    let userData = [];
    const databaseUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'backend/database.json';
    
    // Attempt to read the file
    let databaseContent = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(databaseUri);
    if (databaseContent) {
      userData = JSON.parse(databaseContent);
    }

    const existingUser = userData.find(user => user.username === username);
    if (existingUser) {
      console.log('Username already exists.');
      return false;
    }

    userData.push({ username, password });
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(databaseUri, JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2));
    console.log('User added successfully.');
    return true;
 } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return false;
 }
}
```

This is my function that reads a JSON file and writes the user credentials entered

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { addUserCredentials } from '../backend/AddUser';

export default function SignUpScreen() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    if (username.trim() === '' || password.trim() === '' || confirmPassword.trim() === '') {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please fill in all fields');
    } else if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Passwords do not match');
    } else {
      addUserCredentials(username, password);
      Alert.alert('Success', 'Sign-up successful');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Sign Up</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Confirm Password"
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={confirmPassword}
        onChangeText={text => setConfirmPassword(text)}
      />
      <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={handleSignUp} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 50,
    width: 300,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
});
```

This my sign up page that I takes these values from user input (username and password). The issue is that I am having an error that with the readAsStringAsync. I checked the file path and I pretty sure it is correct. The database.json file that stores all the user's credentials is located in the directory called backend in the project directory. The error is saying that the file is not readable but I checked the file permissions, file existence, and made sure that I installed the expo file system package as well. I am not sure what the reason I am getting this error message. Would appreciate any feedback, thanks.